# form->isValid() empty my model

Tags: php, forms, validation, zend-framework2

I have a big model with around 13 attributs.
I want to update a few value of them using a form.

But actually using $form->isValid() empty my model and set only value which are feeded in my form or have an inputFilter setted.

Are they a way to avoid it ?

Comment: please show your form model . i think you have added filter to all form fields thats why `wrong` data get filtered

Comment: Please show some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout Validation Groups

```
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html#validation-groups
```

You can partially validate your model, and only get back the values in the Validation Group.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have set filter for all the fields in form ,
check what you are getting with this .

```
$unfiltered = $form->getUnfilteredValues();
print_r($unfiltered);
```